# Laravel Eloquent version of "NOT IN" SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Just need the Eloquent ORM format of this query.. giving a headache for a while.

```
SELECT * FROM players WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT player_id FROM team_requests)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Try this.
First you Can Select all Player IDs.

> $player_ids = TeamRequest::select('player_id')->get();

Then you  can find Players

> Player::whereNotIn('user_id', $player_ids)->get();

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely break it into two pieces to start with:

```
$player_ids = TeamRequest::all()->pluck('player_id')->toArray();
```

then

```
Player::whereNotIn('user_id', $player_ids)->get();
```

should give you your anser. Then if you want it in one expression, maybe try

```
Player::whereNotIn('user_id',
  TeamRequest::all()->pluck('player_id')->toArray()
)->get();
```

Comment: Both versions will create an unnecessary SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Player` model has a one-to-many relationship `teamRequests`, then:

```
Player::doesntHave('teamRequests')->get();
```

The relationship method may look like this:

```
public function teamRequest() {
    return $this->hasMany(TeamRequest::class, 'player_id', 'user_id');
}
```